# How does UpdateModel know what to update in MVC EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database table called `Group` that has an `ID`, a `Name`, and a couple more columns not relevant to this question. When submitting the form after changing the name I fetch the entry from the database, then use `UpdateModel(entry)` to update what was submitted by the user.

The question I have is how does EntityFramework/the context/the code magically know what needs to be updated? Why isn't the `group` parameter used? Can anyone explain this or point me to the right place to understand this concept?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Group group)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var entry = db.Group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == group.ID);
        UpdateModel(entry); // <-- Why don't I need to supply group here?
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(group);
}
```

Comment: form `ChangeTracker` class. see [this](https://entityframework.net/change-tracker)

Comment: [Change Tracking in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)